# Why is Rails session ID stored in cookie is unique to the browser, and doesn't change when a user logs out?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authentication, authlogic

I'm experiencing a bizarre issue with the way Rails stores session ID's for users. I can't imagine this is the intended behavior, but I'm also not sure what I'm doing to cause it to work this way.

I'm using a Redis cache store instead of cookies:

```
AppName::Application.config.session_store(
  :cache_store,
  key: '_appname_session',
  secret: 'secret_token',
  secure: true
)
```

Where `secret_token` is a hard coded token that was generated in the past.

Whenever I log into my application, it creates a cookie:

```
Name: _appname_session
Content: randomly_generated_token
```

However, if I log out, then log in as a completely different user, `randomly_generated_token` stays the same.

I'm using authlogic as my authentication library. Any insight as to why this is occurring, or how I can force it to be unique, would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with authlogic but to properly "log out" a user you should call `reset_session` which will invalidate the session id and issue a new session id. Not  `session.delete(:user_id)` which you commonly see in tutorials and homemade auth schemes. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-fixation-countermeasures

Comment: @max This was the issue! Thank you very much, if you want to add it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: `ActionController::Metal#reset_session` ends your rails session, and `Authlogic::Session::Base#destroy` ends your authlogic session. These are two different meanings of the word "session".